# Why is the schema not created within SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

A spring boot application (3.1.4).

For faster progress with flyway migrations the schema should be created and written to a file. This is the configuration:

application.yml:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:8080}

application:
  title: MyApp
  version: @project.version@
  buildnumber: @buildNumber@

spring:
  profiles:
    active: @activatedProperties@
  
  jpa:
      open-in-view: false
```

application-createsql.yml

```
flyway:
  enabled: false

spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:h2:file:./data/myDB"
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: password

    jpa:
      properties:
        jakarta:
          persistence:
            schema-generation:
              create-source: metadata
              scripts:
                action: drop-and-create
                create-target: create.sql
                drop-target: drop.sql
```

If the application is started with this profile nothing happens, I would expect the file create.sql to be created within project root folder. Also if I exchange jakarta with javax nothing happens.

What could be the reason for this?

Thanks and Best Regards
matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set additional property,

```
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
```

In yaml form,

```
spring:
    jpa:
      defer-datasource-initialization:true
```